# Is it possible to make function Import to return custom Array or should I use custom sql for it?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I've got procedure which returns different kind of tables but I can't see how can I import it to Entity model.

I can see variants there:

- None
- Scalars
- Complex ( what is it? )
- Entities

So but I need just something alike Array or DataTable because I don't know what there will be.   How to make such import using Entity framework? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Entity Framework prior to EF5 does not directly support stored procedures that return multiple resultsets. There is an extension that can do this: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions. Also I've found an article for EF5 & EF6: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675933/Returning-Multiple-Result-Sets-from-an-Entity-Fram

Comment: I'm asking about Entity Framework Function Import. Where can I find something alike DataSet there?

Comment: @Heather I'm sorry, my mistake. AFAIK, Entity Framework prior to EF5 does not directly support stored procedures that return multiple resultsets. There is an extension that can do this: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions. Also I've found an article for EF5 & EF6: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675933/Returning-Multiple-Result-Sets-from-an-Entity-Fram